# Flutter asset image for map markers does not load on iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I can load my custom marker images on the in the live chrome session with

```
String pngName = "assets/myMarker.png";
return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
    const ImageConfiguration(),
    pngName
);
```

but it fails to load the marker for iOS simulators. The map shows the red, generic  google map spot markers. Not sure what to do, I understand I should get the path from the `AssetsBundle` somehow, but I do not find a method that would return the root path for the assets folder that I could append the filename to? I would guess `fromAssetsImage` would do that internally...